# Insert to table from textfields - empty fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-express

I have some problems: The code below updates the table with a new row, but all the fields in this row are empty. I want to get the input data from the textfields into a new row in the table Members.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public partial class Default4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtFirstName.Text = "";
        txtLastName.Text = "";
        txtAdress.Text = "";
        txtResidence.Text = "";
        txtEmail.Text = "";
    }
    protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
            WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Members(FirstName, LastName, Adress, Residence, Email) VALUES (@txtFirstName, @txtLastName, @txtAdress, @txtResidence, @txtEmail)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtFirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtLastName", txtLastName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtAdress", txtAdress.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtResidence", txtResidence.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtEmail", txtEmail.Text);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            lblConfirm.Text = "Database updated, insert confirmed!";

            txtFirstName.Text = "";
            txtLastName.Text = "";
            txtAdress.Text = "";
            txtResidence.Text = "";
            txtEmail.Text = "";
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

If I change this line:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Members(FirstName, LastName, Adress, Residence, Email) VALUES (@txtFirstName, @txtLastName, @txtAdress, @txtResidence, @txtEmail)", con);
```

To something like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Members(FirstName, LastName, Adress, Residence, Email) VALUES ('@txtFirstName', '@txtLastName', @txtAdress, @txtResidence, @txtEmail)", con);
```

It will print out a row with fields like this: 
| @txtFirstName | @txtLastName | [Empty] | [Empty] | [Empty] |

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your press the register button, the `Page_Load` executes, emptying your textboxes, then the `btnRegister_Click` executes. At this point your textboxes are blank.

you need to add a check in the Page_Load event

```
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
      ... // code to empty the textboxes
   }
```

[Page.IsPostBack property on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

heres the problem....

```
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        lblConfirm.Text = "Database updated, insert confirmed!";

        txtFirstName.Text = "";
        txtLastName.Text = "";
        txtAdress.Text = "";
        txtResidence.Text = "";
        txtEmail.Text = "";
    }
```

^^^^^^ resetting all the fields here will make no difference.It will happen after each postback.

try this

```
if(!IsPostBack)
   {
            txtFirstName.Text = "";
            txtLastName.Text = "";
            txtAdress.Text = "";
            txtResidence.Text = "";
            txtEmail.Text = "";
   }
```

Therefore the users input will not be reset to nothing on button click..

There are better ways of achieving your goals here...